# content getting cut off by parent div

Tags: html, css

The image to the right is getting cut off by the parent div which has overflow:hidden applied. Maybe this is not even possible how I have this set up but if it is, how can I make the image not get cut off?
https://jsfiddle.net/kimwild/q3vwthky/2/

```css
figure#main-img,
figure#main-img-black {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure#main-img-black {
  background-color: #000000;
}
section#title {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 0 .83333%;
  /* 10px / 1200px */
  max-width: 1200px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section#title #hgroup {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9020;
  position: relative;
}
.parent {} figure#main-img img,
figure#main-img-black img {
  /* max-width: 1400px;*/
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
section#title h1.white,
section#title h1.black {
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 0;
}
section#title h1.white {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
section#title h2.white,
section#title h2.black {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 40%;
}
section#title h2.white {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<figure id="main-img-black">
  <section id="title">
    <div id="hgroup">
      <div class="parent">
        <img src="http://hauppauge.com/responsive/pics/hdpvr-rocket_top5.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <h1 class="white">HD PVR 
      Rocket </h1>
      <h2 class="white">Portable Game Recorder</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this is to put a `float: right;` on `.parent` like this :

```
.parent { float :right; }
```

Also, remove position absolute on the img.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3vwthky/5/)

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing this. On some pages there will be less text and different height images.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This way worked as well as below.

Answer (score 0):

Section inside figure is a strange idea. If you use figure, why not use figcaption.

```
<figure class='product'>
  <img src="http://hauppauge.com/responsive/pics/hdpvr-rocket_top5.jpg" alt="HD PVR Rocket">
  <figcaption>
    <h1 class="white">HD PVR Rocket</h1>
    <h2 class="white">portable game recorder</h2>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
figure {
  margin: 0;
}

.product {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: right;
}

.product img {
  width: 96%;
  padding: 2%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

.product figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 96%;
  padding: 2%;
  text-align: left;
}

.product figcaption h1 {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.product figcaption h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asak5uaq/)

Comment: I am happy I could help!